# confused about dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have the following dict

```
commands = {

'cmd1':"configure terminal",

'cmd2':"router",

'cmd3':"MPLS"

}
```

when I execute the following code:

```
   `for cmd in commands:
            print(cmd)
```

I always get cmd3 as 1st print, why is that?

I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Dictionary is unordered; the order of the key is implementation-dependent and might change when you insert or remove items

Comment: Use OrderedDict if you want insertion order to be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionaries are unordered. Things will come out of them in some order when you iterate over them, but the order probably will not be the same order in which you added them. This is by design.

You can use `collections.orderedDict` if you need order. Or, in this case, since the keys are not actually needed, just use a list.

Comment: WHen I use ordereddict, the cmd2 always comes 1st.

Comment: How did you initialise the OrderedDict? Because you can't just pass it a dictionary and expect it to work, you'd have to use something like: `OrderedDict([('cmd1', ...), ('cmd2', ...), ...])`

Answer (score 0):

To see what the values are - use sorted on the resulting list of items:

```
for key,value in sorted(commands.items()):
       print(key)
       print(value)
       print commands[key] # same as line above
```

Comment: gives error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: .iteritems() was missing there. My fault.

Comment: Again error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: I used items, but still the same result. I still get 2 value as the the 1st print.

Comment: Sorry, typo - just items. it will print out everything. If you need them sorted - use  sorted(commands.items())